# Compile android APK from source code

Tags: java, android, apk

I have a source code of Android app written in Java. I want to make some changes to the code and compile as android app.
I have no knowledge on Java Android app.

Is there anyway for me to compile and make it as APK by using any software?

Here is the [source](https://github.com/NoahY/q2android/tree/master/src/org/noahy/q2android):-

Comment: try reading about android first

Comment: hire a freelancer to help you

Comment: This looks helpful: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Answer (score 2):

If the changes you are planning to make in `q2android` app are simple enough and you know what you are changing then `sur007` has captured all that you need. Else it's a job for someone hands on with Android development.

Another big **warning** for you: The app is over ***4 years old*** , which means you have to carefully choose API and Sdk Mix/Max versions..  managing version support can be hectic even for seasoned android developers - so be prepared to face `backward compatibility` and `API depreciated` issues

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Download the [IDE](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), import the github project and run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse ADT.In order to publish it into Google Play you should sign it.It generates APK and you can sign it via ADT easily.

Answer (score 0):

First, u need download IDE and sdk to prepare build environment,u can get these in [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html):

Second, u need import ActionBarSherlock as lib project, u can follow below link to check out [these](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) code and import to your workspace.

`command: git clone https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock [your folder]`

u can add actionbarSherlock project as a lib project in Q2Android project.

Then,u can build this project.

Answer (score 0):

You will be glad to know that you can start your Android application development on either of the following operating systems:

```
Microsoft Windows XP or later version.

Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later version with Intel chip.

Linux including GNU C Library 2.7 or later.
```

Second point is that all the required tools to develop Android applications are freely available and can be downloaded from the Web. Following is the list of software's you will need before you start your Android application programming.

```
Java JDK5 or JDK6

Android SDK

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (optional)

Android Development Tools (ADT) Eclipse Plugin (optional)
```

For further enquiry you can go through

1.[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_environment_setup.htm)

The other way would be to use Android Studio

Before you start this class, be sure you have your development environment set up. You need to:

```
Download Android Studio.
Download the latest SDK tools and platforms using the SDK Manager.
```

Go through this [Migrate to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) to import your project onto Android Studio

2. [Android site](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Simple, follow these steps....

1.Download & install android studio
2. Install Java SDK (ie) jdk
3. Open android studio
4. Choose File->import
5. Select your source code